# Sorting Columns reactjs table

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a reactjs table for an assignment and am having trouble getting a sorting component working on the columns of my table. Most of this was duplicated from a previous post and I tried to integrate my data into the mold, but I am getting no results. Any idea why the code I have might not be working? Thanks!

```
class UserTable extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     users: this.props.users,
     sort: {
   column: null,
   direction: 'desc',
  }
    }
}


onSort = (column) => {

return e => {
    const direction = this.state.sort.column ? (this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc') : 'desc'
    const sortedUsers = this.state.users.sort((a, b) => {
        if (column === 'name.first') {
            const nameA = a.name.first.toUpperCase() // ignore upper and lowercase
            const nameB = b.name.first.toUpperCase() // ignore upper and lowercase

            if (nameA < nameB)
                return -1
            if (nameA > nameB)
                return 1
            else return 0
        }
        else {
            return a.name.first - b.name.first
        }
    })

    if (direction === 'desc') {
        sortedUsers.reverse()
    }

    this.setState({
        users: sortedUsers,
        sort: {
            column,
            direction,
        },
    })
}
}

const setArrow = (column) => {
let className = 'sort-direction';

if (this.state.sort.column === column) {
  className += this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? ' asc' : ' desc';
}

return className;
};

render() {
return (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th onClick={this.onSort('name.first')}>
          First Name
          <span className={this.setArrow('name.first')}></span>
        </th>
        <th onClick={this.onSort('name.last')}>
          Last Name
          <span className={this.setArrow('name.last')}></span>
        </th>
        <th onClick={this.onSort('company')}>
          Company
          <span className={this.setArrow('company')}></span>
        </th>
        <th onClick={this.onSort('phone')}>
          Phone
          <span className={this.setArrow('phone')}></span>
        </th>
        <th onClick={this.onSort('email')}>
          Email
          <span className={this.setArrow('email')}></span>
        </th>
        <th onClick={this.onSort('birthdate')}>
          Birthdate
          <span className={this.setArrow('birthdate')}></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {this.state.users.map((user, index) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{user.name.first}</td>
            <td>{user.name.last}</td>
            <td>{user.company}</td>
            <td>{user.phone}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
            <td>{user.birthdate}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<UserTable users={users} />,  document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. You are, by far, a much better debugger, just with a little effort. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The person best suited to figure this out is actually you, as you have everything in the program, including things you might not realize are connect so you didn't show us, as well as knowing exactly what the final product you want to be is. It's more benificial for you to learn how to debug for yourself.

Comment: I figured it all out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a function in `onSort` handler since event handlers take reference of a function but in your case they are getting `undefined` because you are invoking function and nothing returned.

So you code should looks like this:

```
onSort = column => {
    return e => {
        const direction = this.state.sort.column ? (this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc') : 'desc'
        const sortedUsers = this.state.users.sort((a, b) => {
            if (column === 'name.first') {
                const nameA = a.name.first.toUpperCase() // ignore upper and lowercase
                const nameB = b.name.first.toUpperCase() // ignore upper and lowercase

                if (nameA < nameB)
                    return -1
                if (nameA < nameB)
                    return 1
                else return 0
            }
            else {
                return a.name.first - b.name.first
            }
        })

        if (direction === 'desc') {
            sortedUsers.reverse()
        }

        this.setState({
            users: sortedUsers,
            sort: {
                column,
                direction,
            },
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped my code compile. How would I go about making it so that each of my columns can be sorted, rather than just my 'name.first' column?

Comment: Hi Denys, I am stuck with one issue in React which is related to sorting of rows in React-Table. Can you give me some idea how can I sort elements in this case - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68359658/1649217